# I'll be at the concert tomorrow evenif/while/if it means queuing for tickets all night

Tags: clauses, nuance

In my Cambridge English book there is a practice sentence where I have to put in a clause. The options are 'while', 'despite', 'if' and 'even if'. The context is contrast clauses.
The sentence is:

> I'll be at the concert tomorrow ... it means queuing for tickets all night

I understand that to give contrast 'even if' is the correct answer. However, if I do not want to give contrast would it also be correct to insert 'while'? Or even more extreme; if someone likes to queue for tickets, would it be correct to use 'if' as well?

Comment: Using *while* would be a little odd. I would prefer *although*.

Comment: Once we start asking "what if" questions, the sky's the limit: *if* someone likes cookies, could we change "tickets" to "cookies"? (Yes.) This is an exercise primarily in context; change the context, and you have yourself a new exercise.

Comment: *While* adds the idea of things happening at the same time. This may be confusing. I think this question belongs on ELL site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's consider the options:

1. **while**: this would mean "for as long as". That doesn't seem to make sense. Being at the concert will either involve queueing for tickets all night, or it won't. There isn't a point in time at which it will stop involving that, and even if it did it would be strange for someone to be at the concert only conditionally on there being a long queue. Note that if the two clauses were reversed ("while...I'll be...) it would definitely be acceptable.
2. **despite** : takes a gerund ("despite it meaning"), not a present tense ("despite it means"). This would be grammatically wrong.
3. **if** : like '"while" this is grammatically correct. I will be at the concert provided I have to queue for tickets all night. Normally this implies that if I don't have to queue for tickets then I won't go to the concert, which would be strange behaviour.
4. **even if** It specifically means that queueing for tickets all night will not prevent me from going to the concert, without implying that *not* queueing for tickets *will* prevent me. **This is probably the answer being looked for.**

However it is common among native English speakers to informally use "if" in place of "even if" - witness the common phrase "I'll do this if it kills me." - and some might use "while" But the use of "even if" is clearer and more formally correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer DJClayworth, this has answered my question!